# mysql, php , how to count results that are the same?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table that has `users` and the `pages` that they visited.
i might have user `user1` that visited pages: `index.php` 3 times and 'test.php' 4 times.

then user `user2` that visited pages: `index.php` 6 times and 'test.php' 10 times.
what i want to do is to display the most visited pages by user in order.

any ideas?
thanks

edit: table schema. table name `findme`

```
talentnum | page_name
user1     | test.php
user1     | test.php
user1     | index.php
user2     | test.php
user3     | index.php
```

Comment: Please provide your schema for the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT
  TALENTNUM,
  PAGE_NAME,
  COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM FINDME
GROUP BY TALENTNUM, PAGE_NAME
ORDER BY CNT DESC
```

Comment: @Patrioticcow This should return each page for each user with the count of times they visited that page. Also I added an order by and updated the query to use your schema.

Answer (score 1):

w/o knowing your table schema:

```
SELECT user, page, count(*)
FROM users u
JOIN page p
ON u.user_id = p.user_id
GROUP BY user, page
ORDER BY user, page DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a user loads a page insert a row into the table to record his ID and the Page visited. You can then run an SQL query

```
SELECT talentnum,page_name,COUNT(page_name) FROM findme
GROUP BY talentnum,page_name
ORDER BY COUNT(page_name) DESC
```